# Python - save csv file with tab separated words in separate cell

Tags: python, csv

I have this input file:

```
one\tone
two\ttwo
three\tthree
```

With a tab between each word.

I am trying to save it in a csv file where each word ends up in its own cell.  This is my code:

```
import csv

input = open('input.txt').read()
lines = input.split('\n')

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)   
   for line in lines:
     writer.writerow([line])
```

However, both words end up in the same cell:

[image]

How do I change the code so that each word ends up in its own cell?

Comment: Try `writer.writerow(line.split("\t"))`?

Comment: @Shadow: you were the first to respond - please write an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `writerow` method in the [CSV writer library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) takes a list of columns.

Currently, you are providing your whole string the value of the first column

```
 writer.writerow([line])
```

Instead, try splitting the string by `\t`, thus creating a list of each individual word and provide that to the library instead.

```
writer.writerow(line.split("\t"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import csv

input = open('input.txt').read()
lines = input.split('\n')

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)   
   for line in lines:
     writer.writerow(line.split('\t'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the input lines into a list, so that `csv.writer()` will put them into seperate columns. Try:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)   
   for line in lines:
       writer.writerow(line.split('\t'))
```